# How to organize less classes correctly

Tags: html, css, less

I am newbie in `LESS` world, so I have question about the way I can organize my classes.

Here is my current `less` code for classes.

```
.links {
    width: 9em;
    height: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50px);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50px);
    transform: translate(0,-50px);
    a {
        i {
            position: relative;
            color: @colorMainGreen;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 0 13px;
            z-index: 100;
            &::after {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                left: -7px;
                top: -7px;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border: 1px solid @colorMainGreen;
                z-index: -1;
                border-radius: 3px;
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
                     -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
                        transform: rotate(45deg);
            }
            &:hover i {
                color:  #fff;
            }
        }
        &:hover {
            i {
                &:hover {
                    background-color: @colorMainGreen;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make things clear, here is compiled version

```
.links {
  width: 9em;
  height: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  transform: translate(0, -50px);
}
.links a i {
  position: relative;
  color: #68c3a3;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 13px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.links a i::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: -7px;
  top: -7px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #68c3a3;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.links a i:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}
.links a:hover i:hover {
  background-color: #68c3a3;
}
```

And I need to add in my less code this part

```
.links,
.links a i,
.links a i::after {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    -o-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
```

As you can see

I need to apply this class in links and it's child classes.
I am not aware of all available methods, so I can only consider using mixins and add it in each class, but this is code duplication. Maybe there is another way to accomplish this, I've read about extension, maybe it is possible to use it here ? 
In OOP languases this would simple inheritence. 
Please suggest the best way to organize such code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer to your question is instead of writing selectors that target specific html structure (i.e `.links a i`) write reusable, generic classes that you sprinkle on your html or use them as a mixin (since every class is considered a mixin in LESS).

Better yet, use a known and documented CSS methodology, such as OOCSS which promotes the use of generic css classes.

---

Long answer: I can tell you are not very experienced with CSS and therefore you are not yet familiar with common practices and abstractions that can be used t structure your CSS code. Here's a few pointers to help you, not just with LESS but CSS in general.

General CSS Structure:

1. Use as little nesting as possible. Nesting is more of a curse than a boon as I'm sure you'll figure out soon enough. It creates **long selectors** that are hard to read, hard to refactor and are **bad for performance**. But the worse thing about nesting is that it **enforces a specific html structure**.

   Instead apply your namespace using single classes (e.g `.links-anchor` instead of `.links a`) that way the namespace of `links` is preserved but no html structure is enforced. (i understand this html structure is too basic to see the benefits, but bear with me for now)
2. Do not use element names in your selectors (this is called qualifying selectors). This again **enforces a specific html structure** (e.g you can only use an `i` element in your current css) and it affects performance because **browsers parse your selectors from right to left**.

   That means that when a browser sees `.links a` it will first find **all anchors in your page** and then filter them down to those that are under an element with a class of `.links`.

   Instead, create single classes for every element you wish to style and namespace them using a parent that makes sense semantically. E.g: `.links`, `.links-anchor` and `.links-anchor-i` (i have no idea what the `i` element is meant to be represent in your code.
3. Which leads me to my next point. Write semantic classes that describe what you are styling rather than targeting random html elements like `i`. This includes both your root element as well as any children you are styling.

   For example if those `links` are meant to be your main navigation component, choose a classname called `.main-navigation` for your root element then `.main-navigation-link` and `.main-navigation-label` (if that what `i` was referring too)

There are just some of the ways you can improve your CSS. I suggest reading the excellent http://cssguidelin.es/ page, which contains a lot more improvements as well as examples and resources. After reading through that and understanding some of the pitfalls of CSS, I suggest to start using an existing CSS methodology such as [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki), [BEM](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) or [ITCSS](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/manage-large-scale-web-projects-new-css-architecture-itcss-41514731)

---

Now onwards to LESS/Tooling suggestions

1) Try to use nesting only for styling the **variations** element your selector is targetting and pseudo elements (`:before` and `:after`). This is possible via the `&` operator which is a shorthand for your original selector.

```
.navigation-link {
    &:hover {...}
    &:active {...}

    &:before {...}
}
```

2) Add a post-processor to your CSS build, such as [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) which allows you to write **clean, web standard compliant CSS** and that will later get expanded to the prefixed versions that your supported browsers require.

3) Avoid "magic numbers" where you can. Instead use LESS variables and calculations, so that it's self explanatory where that number comes from.

```
@layout-header-height: 40px;
@layout-padding: 10px;
.layout-header {position: fixed; height: @layout-header-height; ...}
.layout-body { padding-top: (@layout-header-height + @layout-padding); ...}
```

---

I think that's enough for now, but there are loads more info out there.

- Look up articles by CSS legends such as Harry Roberts (CSS Wizardy), Nicole Sullivan (OOCSS), Jonathan Snook (SMACSS) and Nicolas Gallagher.
- Look at the source code for big css projects such as Bootstrap and Foundation and see how they are using preprocessors to structure their code
- And of course keep asking questions on Stackoverflow!

I hope this helps and good luck :)

Comment: Thanks ! You helped me a lot !

Comment: To be honest, this is not my personal code, I use it from free template (also available in paid version).

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by creating 1 more class. Just for example

create 1 more extra class like below and you can add this class into another class. so you don't need to write this code repeatedly. it is mixins provided by LESS.

```
.trans {
   -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms;
    -o-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
```

Now, you can add this class into all your 3 classes like below.

```
.links {
     .trans;
     a{
        i{
            .trans;
            &:after{
                .trans;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

to be more precise you can include below mixin classes so you don't need to write even this 4 lines for transition.

[MIXIN LIBS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/useful-css3-less-mixins/)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for (and if not, then not to worry) but if you are learning LESS because you want to have more organised, easier-to-maintain stylesheets, then *grouping-selectors-by-style*, rather than *grouping-styles-by-selector* is one alternative approach (using standard CSS) which - although not widely adopted - offers as much control and ease of maintainance as pre-processors like SASS and LESS (but, self-evidently, does not require compliling).

*Grouping-selectors-by-style* is not for everyone, but because it breaks stylesheets up into a series of mini-stylesheets, I find (personally) it makes CSS debugging very easy indeed.

It also gets rid of the need for variables.

**E.g.** To take a simple example, if `h1` and `nav h2` and `footer h2` are the same color blue and `aside h2` and `article h2` and `header h2` are all red and you decide you want `h1` and `nav h2` and `footer h2` to be green, then a single update to a stylesheet where selectors are grouped by style will suffice, from:

```
.TEXT-COLOR,
h1, nav h2, footer h2 {color: rgb(0,0,191);}
header h2, aside h2, article h2 {color: rgb(255,0,0);}
```

to:

```
.TEXT-COLOR,
h1, nav h2, footer h2 {color: rgb(0,191,0);}
header h2, aside h2, article h2 {color: rgb(255,0,0);}
```

In a conventional stylesheet, where styles are grouped by selector, you'd need to make at least 2 changes from:

```
h1 {color: rgb(0,0,191);}
h2 {color: rgb(0,0,191);}
header h2, aside h2, article h2 {color: rgb(255,0,0);}
```

to:

```
h1 {color: rgb(0,191,0);}
h2 {color: rgb(0,191,0);}
header h2, aside h2, article h2 {color: rgb(255,0,0);}
```

and bear in mind this example is deliberately simple. If you were changing `margin`, `padding`, `font-size` and `box-shadow` all at once - that would be 4 changes in a stylesheet where selectors are grouped by style... but at least 8 changes in a stylesheet where styles are grouped by selector.

Here is your stylesheet above, with the selectors grouped by style:

```
.POSITION,
.links, .links a i::after {position: absolute;}
.links a i {position: relative;}

.CO-ORDINATES,
.links {top: 40%; left: 50%;}
.links a i {z-index: 100;}
.links a i::after {top: -7px; left: -7px; z-index: -1;}

.WIDTH_HEIGHT,
.links {width: 9em; height: 4em;}
.links a i::after {width: 30px; height: 30px;}

.MARGIN_PADDING,
.links {margin: -20px 0 0 -45px;}
.links a i {margin: 0 13px;}

.TEXT-COLOR,
.links a i {color: #68c3a3;}
.links a i:hover i {color: #fff;}

.TEXT-PRESENTATION,
.links a i {font-size: 16px;}

.BACKGROUND,
.links a:hover i:hover {background-color: #68c3a3;}

.BORDER,
.links a i::after {border: 1px solid #68c3a3; border-radius: 3px;}

.MISCELLANEOUS,
.links {opacity: 0;}

.PSEUDO-ELEMENTS,
.links a i::after {content: '';}

.TRANSFORM,
.links {
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -50px);
   -moz-transform: translate(0, -50px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50px);
     -o-transform: translate(0, -50px);
        transform: translate(0, -50px);
}


.links a i::after {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel like I have to downvote this. Maybe I'm starting to become an old man, because this is the first time I saw css structure like that and it looks horrible to me. You are not reusing any code, just splitting up in different files in terms of what it does, instead of what you are styling and creating ever-growing selectors. You are basically using the `extend` feature of SASS without it. Doing something like this would only make sense if you are writing some sort of CSS reset and even then, there are better ways to do it.

Comment: It's okay, @Dogoku - as I wrote above, it's not for everyone. It will look horrible to some... and beautiful to others. I started grouping selectors by styles back in January 2013 (it's based on the DRY CSS approach) and I love it and have never looked back. When it comes to the CSS on the various sites I work on, the ratio of time I spend maintaining CSS as opposed to writing it is about 8:1. Formatting my CSS like this means I never have to look for a stray style or comb through a stylesheet looking for an obscure selector... I can always find everything I need and update it, instantly.

Comment: Your approach is definitely structured, which is better than complete anarchy which is usually the case in beginner CSS. However I see some fundamental flaws in this approach. For example, you'd have to change atleast a dozen files if the styling of just one component of your page changes. Like I said, this approach might be good for a CSS reset or some sort of low level framework, but I wouldn't use it for anything more than that.

Comment: I welcome your feedback, @Dogoku (in fact at least 50% of my motivation for my answer above was in the hopes that I might receive some intelligent, critical feedback, since I'd really like the approach above to be as good as it can be, so I can present it on GitHub. As mentioned above it builds on the ideas of DRY CSS). So, if I may, which dozen files do you foresee would need to be updated if the styling of one component changed? (I promise I'll leave you alone after this, but I need to see where the flaws are... many thanks!)

Comment: I made the assumption (based on the comment about *mini-stylesheets*) that each section of your code is split up into different css files (and bundled via some buildstep at the end). If that's the case then changing one component would mean changing multiple files instead of just 1 file specific to that component. It also means that on a team project, conflicts will increase exponentially, since everyone will have to edit the same files to change different parts of the page. If that's not the case and everything is one big css file, conflicts will still be there.

Comment: Imho, there's a lot more anti-patterns here. Duplicating selectors, asemantic selectors, overqualifying selectors, nesting (and therefore locking into a specific html structure). Imagine that you have to change your html structure from a `ul > li > a` to a `div` based one or adding another level before the `a`. The amount of lines of code changes required here is crazy! You can achieve exactly the same result (grouping selectors by style) by using something like OOCSS (e.g how semantic-ui does it) and move the styles into classes that get added to your html (but it makes html more verbose)

Comment: Many thanks, @Dogoku. I see from your comments here (and in your answer above) that for many years I've been doing selectors "all wrong". I've long understood the recommendation not to use `ids` in selectors (given they override both classes & elements) but, by analogy, I then thought the optimal outcome was to try to avoid using classes as well, wherever possible. Now I see that `ids` are best avoided in selectors because they are _too specific_, `elements` are best avoided because they are _not specific enough_ (which I'd never grasped before). The Goldilocks option is to use `classes`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118728/discussion-between-rounin-and-dogoku).

Answer (score 0):

I have asked myself multiple times when started with sass.
However, nesting is not the must option and you will make handling pure .css an nightmare for some developers, who might not want to use compilers

You should add some classes to your li and simplify nesting when possible.
You can use BEM and follow DRY methodology